# Aboslute positioned content isnt working on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

To my `<h3>` title, I added some content with its `:before`. This content looks like a bottom border.
I positioned this `border` with `position: absolute`, and `top: 40px`.

On big screens, it's working fine, but on small screen, there is some problem, I think because the top position. How can I solve this?

[image: Photo of the site]

```css
.module-head {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px 0
}

.module-head-title {
  color: #32384d;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block
}

.module-head:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 40px;
  background: #32384d;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="module-head">
  <h3 class="module-head-title">Újdonságok, akciós termékek</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: how do you want it to look on mobile? also, is absolute positioning the right thing to do? should you be using a border instead?

Comment: Always under the text, like on monitor. Border? And how can i add width to the border? I dont need it as same width as the text.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It didnt need position absolute, only display block.